# PHP, RegEx. Can't get the match pattern I'm after

Tags: php, regex

So far, I've tried every combination I can think of, and I just can't figure out/find the right one.
I'm after matching a "/me" command within a chatroom I'm currently developing.

The RegEx: `/^\/me (.*)(\|)(.*)?$/i`

Usage:

`/me does something
/me does something else|Hello!`

So far, it matches the second /me command usage (i.e., with the "|" separator) perfectly, but not the first.

Can someone point me in the right direction please? I'm losing my mind here.

I'm after matching
`"/me does something"` and `"/me does something|Hello!"` whilst dropping the "|" if matched

Comment: what do you mean by "dropping the '|'"? Entering `"/me does something|Hello!"` returns with `"/me does somethingHello!"`?

Comment: Not quite. I'm after `/me does something|Hello!` becoming `*User does something* Hello!`.

I've got the haystack running fine, it's the needle I'm struggling to find

Comment: You need to make the matching of the | optional as you have done with the last segment. (Granted the ? on the last segment is redundant.) (\|)? is what you are after. That will match both segments you've mentioned. Then to 'drop' the |, you could use substitution and replace it with whatever character that you would rather see (space for example.)

    matches = (text =~ /^\/me\s(.*)(\|)?(.*)/i);

Then you can replace the second capture group, the one containing the '|' with whatever you see fit. 

*Disclaimer I' don't write PHP so be weary of any syntax malformations.

Comment: @Vlad: I've tried that combination. It returns the entire string as $1 (i.e., the first match), for some strange reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^\/me (.*?)(?:\|(.*))?$/i
```

1. The first line is no match because it contains no `|`
2. You cannot just make the `|` optional because regex are greedy (adding a `?` after `+` and `*` makes them non-greedy, `?:` makes a group non-capturing)
3. If you plan to add other commands then it is probably more readable if you only match `/^\/me (.*)$/i` and handle the rest in a function

Comment: @Magictallguy you are welcome, thanks for accepting, here is the link to visualize https://regex101.com/r/yY6vF9/2

Comment: Hmm `/^\/me ([^|]*)\|?(.+)?$/i` should produce the same result, using not `|` instead of not capturing, there is not just one solution.

Comment: I've tested your syntax and it also works well, but not *exactly* what I'm after.